# Eclipse RCP setSaveAndRestore state is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, perspective

I am working on an RCP application just similar to eclipse with some added features, I am trying to make the RCP to save its last state (mainly its perspective and perspective configuration)

```
public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer) {
    super.initialize(configurer);

    getWorkbenchConfigurer().setSaveAndRestore(true);

    IDE.registerAdapters();
```

But it`s not affecting the RCP at all, as the application resets to its default state after each restart.

any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: How are you running the RCP? What arguments are you specifying when it runs?

Comment: I have checked the arguments and i found the flag "-clearPersistedStat", i removed it and it works !
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not specifying the `-clearPersistedState` or `-persistState false` arguments when you run the RCP. Both these will clear (or not save) the RCP state.